# how to require click on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with this inputs and buttons :

```
<input type="number" id="inputs" name="inputs" min="3" max="48" pattern=".{1,2}" required title="please enter a value between 3 to 48">
<input type="button" id="button1" value="continue">
        <div id="mydiv"></div>
<input type="submit" id ="button2" value="next">
```

And I'm using this javascript code to append number of the "inputs" that the user have insert in this button :

```
$(function()
    {
        var c = 0;

        $("#button1").click(function(){
            c = $("#inputs").val();

            $("#mydiv").html("");

            for(i=1;i<=c;i++)
            {
                $("#mydiv").append('<input type="text" id="name'+i+'" name="name'+i+'" placeholder="name'+i+'">');
                $("#mydiv").append('<input type="number" id="rating'+i+'" name="rating'+i+'" min="1" max="10" placeholder="rating'+i+'"><br/>');
            }
        });

        $("#button2").click(function()
        {
            if(c===0)
            alert('must click on "continue" button');
            });
        });

    });
```

I'm trying to require the user to enter a value in "inputs" (input type) and click on the "continue" (button1) button. With that way it's not working (must enter a value in the "inputs" but can click on "button2" without clicking on "button1"). How do I require the user to click also on the "button1" (continue) ?

Thanks.

Comment: add a keypress handler and check on every key up in the input field if there is a value, if yes, do your handle

Comment: It would probably be better to do proper validation and only present the button(s) when your conditions have been met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
        var c = 0;
        
        $("#button1").click(function() {
            if( !$('#inputs')[0].checkValidity() ) {
                alert( $('#inputs')[0].title );
                return false;
            }
            c = +$("#inputs").val();
            
            $("#mydiv").html("");
            
            for (i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
                $("#mydiv").append('<input type="text" id="name' + i + '" name="name' + i + '" placeholder="name' + i + '">');
                $("#mydiv").append('<input type="number" id="rating' + i + '" name="rating' + i + '" min="1" max="10" placeholder="rating' + i + '"><br/>');
            }
            $('#button2').prop('disabled',false);
        });
        
        $("#button2").click(function() {
            if (c === 0) {
                alert('must click on "continue" button');
            } else {
                alert('Now let us move ahead');
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="inputs" name="inputs" min="3" max="48" pattern=".{1,2}" required title="please enter a value between 3 to 48">
<input type="button" id="button1" value="continue">
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<input type="submit" id="button2" value="next" disabled>
```

Comment: actually the `$('#button2').click()` is useless since the button is disabled :D

Comment: Not it isn't :) Don't you think you owe me an upvote? :) It still does listen to events ... and once `$('#button2').prop('disabled',false);` runs, it will respond to clicks.

Comment: insert 0 in the field ;) op has set a pattern... at least he tried `pattern=".{1,2}"` see my post.

Comment: I see your point. That can easily be fixed; it's just that that was not the OP's primary issue. I'll fix that in a line or two.

Comment: i know this wasn't the issue :) but he added this to his source :D actually we have almost the same answere :D and ill give you a + for this ^^

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function() {
  var c = 0;

  $("#button1").click(function() {

    if ($("#inputs").val().length > 0 && $("#inputs").val().length < 3 && $("#inputs").val() != 0) {
      c = $("#inputs").val();
      $("#mydiv").html("");

      for (i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
        $("#mydiv").append('<input type="text" id="name' + i + '" name="name' + i + '" placeholder="name' + i + '">');
        $("#mydiv").append('<input type="number" id="rating' + i + '" name="rating' + i + '" min="1" max="10" placeholder="rating' + i + '"><br/>');
      }
      $("#button2").prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $("#button2").prop('disabled', true);
      alert("Value is empty / to low / to high. Insert a value between 1 and 99");
    }
  });
    $("#button2").click(function() {
        if(c > 0 && $("#inputs").val() > 0){
            alert('piu piu');
        }
        else{
            alert('sorry, check your inputs');
            $("#button2").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="inputs" name="inputs" min="3" max="48" required title="please enter a value between 3 to 48">
<input type="button" id="button1" value="continue">
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<input type="submit" id="button2" value="next" disabled>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable button2 and make it enable on click of button1, see below code

```
<input type="number" id="inputs" name="inputs" min="3" max="48" pattern=".{1,2}" required title="please enter a value between 3 to 48">
<input type="button" id="button1" value="continue">
        <div id="mydiv"></div>
<input type="submit" id ="button2" value="next" disabled>
```

jQuery

```
$(function()
    {
        var c = 0;

        $("#button1").click(function(){
            c = $("#inputs").val().trim();

            $("#mydiv").html("");

            for(i=1;i<=c;i++)
            {
                $("#mydiv").append('<input type="text" id="name'+i+'" name="name'+i+'" placeholder="name'+i+'">');
                $("#mydiv").append('<input type="number" id="rating'+i+'" name="rating'+i+'" min="1" max="10" placeholder="rating'+i+'"><br/>');
            }

          //enable your button 2 if input has value
          if(c!='')
          $("#button2").removeProp('disabled');
        });

        $("#button2").click(function()
        {
            //submit your form here
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
c = $("#inputs").val();
```

to

```
if($("#inputs").val() != "")
  c = $("#inputs").val();
```